'Cargo install cargo-php' giving - linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
Rustc --version
rustc 1.78.0 (9b00956e5 2024-04-29)
cargo --version
cargo 1.78.0 (54d8815d0 2024-03-26)
OS - On WSL - Ubuntu 22.4
I am running the command Cargo install cargo-php And it throws the error.
I tried with different versions of Rust and ran the rustup toolchain.
rustup toolchain uninstall stable && rustup toolchain install stable ,
Installed sudo apt install libxcb-xfixes0-dev>
I Still see the same error.
Compiling ext-php-rs v0.12.0
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1

 |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/home/ssuresh/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/home/ssuresh/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/home/ssuresh/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:

now" "-Wl,-O1" "-Wl,--strip-debug" "-nodefaultlibs" "-rdynamic"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cargo-installQbAhTj/release/deps/libext_php_rs-b94e59a004df3e03.rlib(2e40c9e35e9506f4-wrapper.o): in function ext_php_rs_process_globals:
          wrapper.c:(.text.ext_php_rs_process_globals+0x7): undefined reference to `core_globals'
          /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cargo-installQbAhTj/release/deps/libext_php_rs-b94e59a004df3e03.rlib(2e40c9e35e9506f4-wrapper.o): in function ext_php_rs_sapi_globals:
    i_globals':
          wrapper.c:(.text.ext_php_rs_sapi_globals+0x7): undefined reference to `sapi_globals'
          /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cargo-installrkMtEp/release/deps/libext_php_rs-31b0a681f1d7129b.rlib(2e40c9e35e9506f4-wrapper.o): in function `ext_php_rs_file_globals':
          wrapper.c:(.text.ext_php_rs_file_globals+0x7): undefined reference to `file_globals'
          /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cargo-installrkMtEp/release/deps/libext_php_rs-31b0a681f1d7129b.rlib(2e40c9e35e9506f4-wrapper.o): in function `ext_php_rs_sapi_module':
          wrapper.c:(.text.ext_php_rs_sapi_module+0x7): undefined reference to `sapi_module'
          /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cargo-installrkMtEp/release/deps/libext_php_rs-31b0a681f1d7129b.rlib(2e40c9e35e9506f4-wrapper.o): in function `ext_php_rs_zend_bailout':



  = note: some `extern` functions couldn't be found; some native libraries may need to be installed or have their path specified
  = note: use the `-l` flag to specify native libraries to link
  = note: use the `cargo:rustc-link-lib` directive to specify the native libraries to link with Cargo (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#rustc-link-lib)

error: could not compile `cargo-php` (bin "cargo-php") due to 1 previous error
error: failed to compile `cargo-php v0.1.9`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-installQbAhTj`.
To reuse those artifacts with a future compilation, set the environment variable `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` to that path

